# How do I take only the first occurrence of a hyphen in sed?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a string, for example `home/JOHNSMITH-4991-common-task-list`, and I want to take out the uppercase part and the numbers with the hyphen between them. I echo the string and pipe it to sed like so, but I keep getting all the hyphens I don't want, e.g.:

```sh
echo home/JOHNSMITH-4991-common-task-list | sed 's/[^A-Z0-9-]//g'
```

gives me:

```
JOHNSMITH-4991---
```

I need:

```
JOHNSMITH-4991
```

How do I ignore all but the first hyphen?

Comment: You could also simply use your own solution, followed by another command that suppresses the trailing hyphens: `sed 's/[^A-Z0-9-]//g;s/-*$//'`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use

```sh
sed 's,.*/\([^-]*-[^-]*\).*,\1,'
```

*POSIX BRE regex details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars
- `/` -  a `/` char
- `\([^-]*-[^-]*\)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `-`, a hyphen, and then again zero or more chars other than `-`
- `.*` - any zero or more chars

The replacement is the Group 1 placeholder, `\1`, to restore just the text captured.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/kpyaLK):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s="home/JOHNSMITH-4991-common-task-list"
sed 's,.*/\([^-]*-[^-]*\).*,\1,' <<< "$s"
# => JOHNSMITH-4991
```

Answer (score 5):

***1st solution:*** With `awk` it will be much easier and we could keep it simple, please try following, written and tested with your shown samples.

```
echo "echo home/JOHNSMITH-4991-common-task-list" | awk -F'/|-' '{print $2"-"$3}'
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, setting field separator as `/` OR `-` and printing 2nd field `-` and 3rd field of current line.

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Using `match` function of `awk` program here.

```
echo "echo home/JOHNSMITH-4991-common-task-list" | 
awk '
match($0,/\/[^-]*-[^-]*/){
  print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)
}'
```

---

---

***3rd solution:*** Using GNU `grep` solution here. Using `-oP` option of `grep` here, to print matched values with o option and to enable ERE(extended regular expression) with `P` option. Then in main program of `grep` using `.*/` followed by `\K` to ignore previous matched part and then mentioning `[^-]*-[^-]*` to make sure to get values just before 2nd occurrence of `-` in matched line.

```
echo "echo home/JOHNSMITH-4991-common-task-list" | grep -oP '.*/\K[^-]*-[^-]*'
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple alternative solution using `cut` with bash string substitution:

```sh
s='home/JOHNSMITH-4991-common-task-list'
cut -d- -f1-2 <<< "${s##*/}"

JOHNSMITH-4991
```

Answer (score 1):

You could match until the first occurrence of the `/`, then clear the match buffer with `\K` and then repeat the character class 1+ times with a hyphen in between to select at least characters before and after the hyphen.

```
[^/]*/\K[A-Z0-9]+-[A-Z0-9]+
```

If supported, using gnu grep:

```
echo "echo home/JOHNSMITH-4991-common-task-list" | grep -oP '[^/]*/\K[A-Z0-9]+-[A-Z0-9]+'
```

Output

```
JOHNSMITH-4991
```

---

If `gnu awk` is an option, using the same pattern but with a capture group:

```
echo "home/JOHNSMITH-4991-common-task-list" | awk 'match($0, /[^\/]*\/([A-Z0-9]+-[A-Z0-9]+)/, a) {print a[1]}'
```

If the desired output is always the first match where the character class with a hyphen matches:

```
echo "home/JOHNSMITH-4991-common-task-list" | awk -v FPAT="[A-Z0-9]+-[A-Z0-9]+" '$0=$1'
```

Output

```
JOHNSMITH-4991
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- could be more than one fwd slash in string
- (after the last fwd slash) there are 2 or more hyphens in the string
- desired output is between last fwd slash and 2nd hyphen

One idea using parameter substitutions:

```
$ string='home/dir/JOHNSMITH-4991-common-task-list'

$ string1="${string##*/}"
$ typeset -p string1
declare -- string1="JOHNSMITH-4991-common-task-list"

$ string1="${string1%%-*}"
$ typeset -p string1
declare -- string1="JOHNSMITH"

$ string2="${string#*-}"
$ typeset -p string2
declare -- string2="4991-common-task-list"

$ string2="${string2%%-*}"
$ typeset -p string2
declare -- string2="4991"

$ newstring="${string1}-${string2}"
$ echo "${newstring}"
JOHNSMITH-4991
```

**NOTES:**

- `typeset` commands added solely to show progression of values
- a bit of typing but if doing this a lot of times in `bash` the overall performance should be good compared to other solutions that require spawning a sub-process
- if there's a need to parse a large number of strings best performance will come from streaming all strings at once (via a file?) to one of the other solutions (eg, a **single** `awk` call that processes all strings will be faster than running the set of strings through a `bash` loop and performing all of these parameter substitutions)